# Postgresql 10 logical replication not working

Tags: postgresql, replication, ubuntu-16.04

I install postgresql 10 using scripts:

```
$ wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

On Master server : xx.xxx.xxx.xx-:

And after that in postgresql.conf:

```
set wal_level = logical
```

On Slave server -:

in postgresql.conf:

```
set wal_level = logical
```

And after all i use below query on master server:

```
create table t1 (id integer primary key, val text);
create user replicant with replication;
grant select on t1 to replicant;
insert into t1 (id, val) values (10, 'ten'), (20, 'twenty'), (30, 'thirty');
create publication pub1 for table t1;
```

And at Slave server:

```
create table t1 (id integer primary key, val text, val2 text);
 create subscription sub1 connection 'dbname=dbsrc user=replicant' publication pub1;
```

But the problem which is i am facing is table are not syncing and as per logical replication when i insert new row on master server, slave server not getting that row.

I am new to postgresql please help me.

Thanks for your precious time.

Now here is my postgresql log for Master server:

```
2017-10-17 11:06:16.644 UTC [10713] replicant@postgres LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "sub_1"
2017-10-17 11:06:16.644 UTC [10713] replicant@postgres DETAIL:  streaming transactions committing after 1/F45EB0C8, reading WAL from 1/F45EB0C8
2017-10-17 11:06:16.645 UTC [10713] replicant@postgres LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 1/F45EB0C8
2017-10-17 11:06:16.645 UTC [10713] replicant@postgres DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
```

Here is my slave server postgresql log:

```
2017-10-17 19:14:45.622 CST [7820] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:45.622 CST [7820] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2017-10-17 19:14:45.670 CST [7821] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:45.670 CST [7821] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2017-10-17 19:14:45.680 CST [7822] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:45.680 CST [7822] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2017-10-17 19:14:50.865 CST [7820] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:50.865 CST [7820] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2017-10-17 19:14:50.917 CST [7821] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:50.917 CST [7821] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2017-10-17 19:14:50.928 CST [7822] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:50.928 CST [7822] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2017-10-17 19:14:55.871 CST [7820] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2017-10-17 19:14:55.871 CST [7820] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
```

And after increasing the max_logical_replication_workers i am getting this:

```
2017-10-17 19:44:45.898 CST [7987] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "sub2", table "t1" has started
2017-10-17 19:44:45.982 CST [7988] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "myadav_test", table "test_replication" h$
2017-10-17 19:44:45.994 CST [7989] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "sub3", table "t1" has started
2017-10-17 19:44:48.621 CST [7987] ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "staging.t1": ERROR:  permission denied for schema staging
2017-10-17 19:44:48.623 CST [7962] LOG:  worker process: logical replication worker for subscription 20037 sync 20027 (PID 7987) exited with exit co$
2017-10-17 19:44:48.705 CST [7988] ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "staging.test_replication": ERROR:  permission denied for$
2017-10-17 19:44:48.707 CST [7962] LOG:  worker process: logical replication worker for subscription 20025 sync 20016 (PID 7988) exited with exit co$
2017-10-17 19:44:48.717 CST [7989] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t1_pkey"
2017-10-17 19:44:48.717 CST [7989] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(10) already exists.
2017-10-17 19:44:48.717 CST [7989] CONTEXT:  COPY t1, line 1
2017-10-17 19:44:48.718 CST [7962] LOG:  worker process: logical replication worker for subscription 20038 sync 20027 (PID 7989) exited with exit co$
2017-10-17 19:44:51.629 CST [8008] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "sub2", table "t1" has started
2017-10-17 19:44:51.712 CST [8009] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "myadav_test", table "test_replication" h$
2017-10-17 19:44:51.722 CST [8010] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "sub3", table "t1" has started
```

Now i finally realize that logical replication is working for postgres database but not for my other database on same server. I am getting permission issue on schema that is is log.

Comment: Check your postgresql logs, there should be some more info

Comment: @JustMe thanks for quick response i update the log in question.

Comment: You might have more luck with this one on the PostgreSQL mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row changes are applied using the rights of the user who owns the subscription. By default that's the user who created the subscription.

So make sure the subscription is owned by a user with sufficient rights. Grant needed rights to tables, or if you can't be bothered, make the subscription owned by a superuser who has full rights to everything.

See:

- [`CREATE SUBSCRIPTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsubscription.html)
- [logical replication - security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logical-replication-security.html)
- [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html)

Comment: Thank for your response ...i will try and let you know @Craig Ringer

Comment: yes its working fine i just use postgres user for creating logical replication and working fine .....